# PyGame can't change song

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I have a remote. When I push 1 it plays the trolol song. When I push 2 it plays the nyan cat song. But I can choose only one song and the code waits till the end of the song. If song 1 is playing, I will change it to song 2. Who can help me?

```
import pygame
import serial
import time
from serial import Serial


ser=serial.Serial("COM3",9600)  #change ACM number as found from ls /dev/tty/ACM*
ser.baudrate=9600
read_ser=ser.readline()#.decode('ascii')
print(read_ser)

if (read_ser==b"1\r\n"):
    pygame.mixer.init()
    pygame.mixer.music.load("C:/Users/jaspe/Downloads/trolol_song.mp3")
    pygame.mixer.music.play()
    print("Trololol")

if (read_ser==b"2\r\n"):
    pygame.mixer.init()
    pygame.mixer.music.load("C:/Users/jaspe/Downloads/nyan_cat.mp3")
    pygame.mixer.music.play()
    print("Kat!!!!")


if (read_ser==b"0\r\n"):
    pygame.mixer.music.stop()
    print("Stop")


while pygame.mixer.music.get_busy():
 continue
```

Comment: shouldn't it run in some loop which check serial again and again (if only readline() doesn't block code)? And this loop should runs instead of your current `while`  which ways to the end of current song.

Comment: Yeah, this sounds like you need a main while loop where you check for input on the COM port and decide what action to take, like starting or stopping the song.